# é seguro criar uma função direto no window ou document?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extensão, userscripts

To criando uma extensão web no chrome e uma das funcionalidades é a criação de user scripts dinâmicos, eles são salvos no `chrome.storage.local`. No `"manifest_version": 2` funciona perfeitamente, mas no `"manifest_version": 3` não, por `content_security_policy` ser muito limitado.

Criar um `<script>` e chamar um arquivo da extensão não serve pra mim, pois preciso que os user scripts tenham acesso a `chrome.storage.local`.

Então eu pensei nesse método abaixo.

```
document["userscript"] = function (){
...
}
```

Comment: ai meu coração.... Sempre que me entendo por DEV JS, sei que devemos evitar alterar 2 coisas: __Objetos globais__ e o __prototype__. Sem falar que eu acho que sua ideia era criar um script no `window` e não no `document`, pois este retorna a referência para o documento contido na janela.

Comment: @CmteCardeal window ou document, não importa qual, ambos funcionam só preciso saber mesmo a questão da segurança

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respondendo estritamente a sua pergunta:

- Não é uma boa prática criar funções na window ou no document
- Toda função fora de um escopo definido vai pra window
- Não é uma boa prática não ter um escopo rs

Sobre a questão da storage, esse link trata desse problema:

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/6qiMo0P-XS4?pli=1

Se vc está sendo barrado por security policies, talvez seja questão de rever o code design assumido. Para ajudar com o código e uma possível saída a explicação necessitaria mais contexto. Se ainda assim vc decidir colocar uma função na window, lembre-se de utilizar um nome específico, descritivo e com baixa chance de conflito, ex: **extensionXyzScript**.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada nesse link ai, a extensão é pra uso pessoal e meu código esta assim `document[extensaoId] = function(){...` pra ser mais exato.